# get value after html tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using python and beautifulsoup module aka bs4. The page that I'm scraping has the following format:

```
<div class="Halls_spec">
   <b>Hall1</b> Thurs.-Wedn.: 21.30
```

I'm using the following code to get info:

```
movie_date = table.select_one("div.Halls_spec")  
movieDate=(movie_date.text.strip())
```

Where I get the following string: `Hall1 Thurs.-Wedn. 21.30`

How am I supposed to get the hall name and the date values separately?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **b** tag along with **next_sibling** to extract the date.

```
movie_date = table.select_one("div.Halls_spec")
movie_date.b.text.strip()
# 'Hall1'
movie_date.b.next_sibling
# ' Thurs.-Wedn.: 21.30'
```

or you could use **next_elements** to get a generator object that you could iterate over:

```
for val in movie_date.b.next_elements:
     print(val)

# Hall1
#  Thurs.-Wedn.: 21.30
```